# Django: Unit test on-memory compiled code

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I am working on a Django project that requires to save and execute fragments of python code.

I just wondering how can I add some "unit tests" to that code, in order to check that it is working as we expect.

Is there some library or methodology that I can implement to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the built in [unit test Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/) is offering.

write the tests in "tests.py" that was created by Django.

run it with "python manage.py test".

Note that:

- In the base directory* if there "__init__.py" file the test will fail
- setUp - is the init function for all tests
- Each test need to start with "test_" at the beginning of the function name.